# NodeJS - Send converted file to client side to download

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

**GOAL**: Allow the user to download a PDF

**Background**: The below code generates a `car.pdf` file and stores it into the main project's directory when `localhost:3000/` is loaded. This is great because I want to find a `Car` by `id` in the database, generate a handlebars template, pass the data from `Car` into it, and generate a PDF from the compiled HTML

**Issue**: Instead of saving the PDF to the main project's directory, I want it to download to the user's computer.

How can I do this?

Here is my code. I am using the NPM package: `html-pdf`

**helpers/export-helper.js**

```
const fs             = require('fs');
const pdf            = require('html-pdf');
const Handlebars     = require('handlebars');

const { Car } = require('./../models/car');

var writePDF = (res) => {

  Car.findById({_id: '58857e256b639400110897af'})
    .then((car) => {
      var source = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/templates/car.handlebars', 'utf8');
      var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
      var file = template(car);
      pdf.create(file, { format: 'Letter' })
        .toFile('./car.pdf', (err, res) => {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }
        });
    })
    .catch((errors) => {
      console.log(errors);
    });
};

module.exports = { writePDF };
```

**routes/home.js**

```
const express  = require('express');
const router   = express.Router();
const { writePDF } = require('./../helpers/export-helpers');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  writePDF();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use res.download for this. Like so

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.download('car.pdf');
});
```

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download

Comment: This isn't scalable though correct? I do not want car.pdf to be saved into the main project's directory as I am currently doing in `export-helper.js`

Comment: So create a folder called PDFs or you can use s3 (I would recommend s3). Maybe make writePDF a promise so that you can access the response from your route

Answer (score 0):

You have to pipe the created pdf with response to client side.

Comment: Can you please show me what you mean by that? Thank you

Comment: var fileStream = file.createReadStream();
  fileStream.pipe(res);